# Applying same UI changes to many elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, interface-builder

A problem I often face is how to apply same changes to many UI elements in the same view.

What I'm looking for is something that would work like this Python pseudocode:

```
def stylize(element): 
    # apply all the UI changes to an element
elements = [button1, button2, button3]
map(stylize,elements)
```

What is the proper Objective-C way to do this (assuming I don't want/can't subclass such UI elements)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For global app styling, consider using `UIAppearance`.

For specific view controllers, `IBOutletCollection` is the most straightforward approach – if you’re using IB, that is. If you aren’t, you can create an `NSArray` variable or property with all the buttons that you want to customize, then iterate over that.

The most literal translation of your Python code would be to

1. add a method to UIButton using a category, e.g. `-[UIButton(YMStyling) ym_stylize]`
2. and then call `[@[button1, button2, button3] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(ym_stylize)]`.

This is rather unnatural in the Cocoa/Obj-C world, so I would recommend sticking to the more idiomatic approaches above. When in Rome, etc…

Comment: So what do Romans do in Obj-C Rome, do they use `IBOutletCollection`?

Comment: Yes, I would think so ;-) Use UIAppearance or IBOutletCollection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python also I didn't understand your question completely. It is not clear for me.

Possibly you are looking for `IBOutletCollection`.

> **IBOutletCollection**
>
> ```
> Identifier used to qualify a one-to-many instance-variable declaration so that Interface Builder can synchronize the display and connection of outlets with Xcode. You can insert this macro only in front of variables typed as NSArray or NSMutableArray.
>
> This macro takes an optional ClassName parameter. If specified, Interface Builder requires all objects added to the array to be instances of that class. For example, to define a property that stores only UIView objects, you could use a declaration similar to the following:
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *views;
>
> For additional examples of how to declare outlets, including how to create outlets with the @property syntax, see “Xcode Integration”.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in UINibDeclarations.h.
> ```
>
> Discussion
>
> For more information about how to use these constants, see
>   “Communicating with Objects”. For information about defining and using
>   actions and outlets in Interface Builder, see Interface Builder User
>   Guide.

Check these links:

1. [UIKitConstantsReference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitConstantsReference/Reference/reference.html)
2. [Using iOS 4′s IBOutletCollection](http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could simply use an NSMutableArray with views in it. Here is an example I made to demonstrate my idea:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 20, 40)];
    [view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 100, 20, 40)];
    [view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    UIView *view3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 100, 20, 40)];
    [view3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    [self.view addSubview:view2];
    [self.view addSubview:view3];

    NSMutableArray *views = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, nil];

    [self changeViews:views];
}

-(void)changeViews:(NSMutableArray *)viewsArray {
    for (UIView *view in viewsArray) {
        [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];//any changes you want to perform
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't add comments to Yang's answer, so I'll say it here:
You seem to ask the same question from the OP post right after you got an answer..